# In Subsonic 2.1 how do I get a strongly typed object from find?

Tags: database, c#-3.0, subsonic, idatareader

In Subsonic 2.1 how do I get type T from Find?

```
        Animal criteria = new Animal();
        IDataReader result = Animal.Find(criteria);
```

I want result to be of type Animal not IDataReader. How can I convert IDataReader to Animal? I hope there is a SubSonic or Framework method to do this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (from the [Getting Started PDF Documentation](http://geekswithblogs.net/scottkuhl/archive/2006/12/09/subsonicdoc.aspx)):

```
IDataReader result = Animal.Find(criteria);
AnimalCollection coll = new AnimalCollection();
coll.Load(result);
result.Close();

// do something with coll
foreach (Animal anm in coll)
{
    // do something with animal object
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I'm now working on getting this into a good extension method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154395/