# In Subsonic 2.1 how do I make this generic call take one generic parameter?

Tags: generics, c#-3.0, subsonic

Using Subsonic 2.1 I want to make my method call to results look like this: `results(searchCriteria)` right now I have to pass the CollectionType as well as the type.

```
Animal searchCriteria = GetSearchCritera();
AnimalCollection results = results<Animal, AnimalCollection>(searchCriteria);
// I want the call to be results(searchCriteria);
```

Here is the results method that I want to just take Y

```
public static T results<Y, T>(Y searchCriteria)
    where Y: ReadOnlyRecord<Y>, new()
    where T:  ReadOnlyList<Y, T>, new()
{
    using (IDataReader results = ReadOnlyRecord<Y>.Find(searchCriteria))
    {
        T a = new  T();
        a.Load(results);
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you *expect* it to know what kind of collection to create if you've only told it about `Animal`? There could be multiple suitable collections.

Comment: Presumably the `Collection` type is always `blahCollection`, where `blah` is the underlying record type.

Comment: @David: You may want to look at the newest version, [SubSonic 3.0](http://subsonicproject.com/)

Comment: Thanks @mellamokb. For the forseable future we are stuck on SubSonic 2 for this particular project. Looks like 3 fixed my untyped issues :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this class:

```
    public class ConcreteList<T> : ReadOnlyList<T, ConcreteList<T>> where T: ReadOnlyRecord<T>, new()
    {
        public ConcreteList() { }
    }
```

changed this code:

```
    public static ConcreteList<T> results2<T>(T searchCriteria)
        where T : ReadOnlyRecord<T>, new()
    {
        using (IDataReader results = ReadOnlyRecord<T>.Find(searchCriteria))
        {
            ConcreteList<T> a = new ConcreteList<T>();
            a.Load(results);
            return a;
        }
    }
```

and I'm able to call it like this:

```
    Animal searchCriteria = GetSearchCritera();
    ConcreteList<Animal> results = results2(searchCriteria);
```

Oh yeah I wanted this to be an extension method:

```
public static class ReadOnlyRecordExtensions
{
    public static ConcreteList<T> ExecuteFind<T>(this T searchCriteria)
            where T : ReadOnlyRecord<T>, new()
    {
        using (IDataReader results = ReadOnlyRecord<T>.Find(searchCriteria))
        {
            ConcreteList<T> list = new ConcreteList<T>();
            list.Load(results);
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```